# Create Function Import on overloaded Stored Procedure in Oracle, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there a way to create a Function Import on an Oracle stored procedure that is overloaded? I have a login sp that is overloaded three times. I tried to create a Function Import for it but EF doesn't let me pick which sp I want to create. It creates the one with the least amount of parameters. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this site for an answer.  I had the same issue and what he suggested works.  I took me a few minutes to set it up though.

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1059538&start=30&tstart=0

Now the issue I am having is creating a stored procedure that returns an output parameter for the ID of the entity.  Seems not to be supported by EF 4.